# What is the best way to merge large files (40gb+)

Tags: file, merge, filesystems

I have tens of files that are 256MB and total in 40GB - These are bin files and i want to make one large bin file to mount..etc I need to merge them into one large file. Sometimes I might have larger packs 60gb to 500gb even.

How can i merge these files using some powershel? batch? vbscript?  and will NTFS handle these large single files or should I use another OS to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Do you mean that you just want them appended? Or are they a specific file format? You talk about "mount"-ing them. From this I assume that they might be something like .ISO files ("BIN" is a really commonly-used and ambiguous file extension). In this case, I don't think you can just concatenate them.

Comment: They are dumps of sequential LBA sectors.. i have merged 3 in memory and back to back it works.. but i have to click merge for each next file in winhex.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On Windows/DOS you can do `copy /b filename1 + filename2 outfilename`

On UNIX/Linux you can do `cat filename1 filename2 > outfilename`

Files of that size should be fine on NTFS

EDIT: You ask in your comment how to do wildcard copying. You can use wildcards in both cases.

On Windows/DOS you can do `copy /b *.txt + *.dat outfilename`

On UNIX/Linux you can do `cat *dat > outfilename`

Comment: How can i make it 4 dos do it for all files in a directory? Like say there are 15 files that need merging.. and then 24? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, NTFS will handle those files. Maximum size of a file on NTFS is 16TB. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Limitations